# Does the classic copy to clipboard need input field/text area field necessarily?

Tags: javascript, jquery, copy, clipboard

I had to copy  a section of text within an anchor tag to clipboard. As suggested on the internet I did
HTML:

```
          <div class="organizer-link">
         <i class="fa fa-link" id="copylink"></i>
         <a href="#" id="linktocopy">https://ticketnshop.com/events/124</a>
          </div>
```

JS:

```
 $("#copylink").click(function () {
         console.log("copy link clicked");
         $('#linktocopy').focus();
         $('#linktocopy').text().select();
         document.execCommand("copy");
        console.log($('#linktocopy').val());

    });
```

But it didnt work.

But then I replaced the anchor tag with a text field and the text was copied.

Does this process strictly require a textarea/input field. If not what have I done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `select()` because you're not focused on a text field (nor a textarea).

Here is a working example using range selection. Maybe you should take a look at [clipboard.js](https://css-tricks.com/native-browser-copy-clipboard/) too.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#copylink").click(function() {
    var containerid = "linktocopy";
    if (document.selection) {
      var range = document.body.createTextRange();
      range.moveToElementText(document.getElementById(containerid));
      range.select().createTextRange();
      document.execCommand("copy");
    } else if (window.getSelection) {
      var range = document.createRange();
      range.selectNode(document.getElementById(containerid));
      window.getSelection().removeAllRanges(range);
      window.getSelection().addRange(range);
      document.execCommand("copy");
      console.log("text copied");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="organizer-link">
  <i class="fa fa-link" id="copylink"></i>
  <a href="#" id="linktocopy">https://ticketnshop.com/events/124</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

your using select() method which is limited to `<input type="text">` fields and `<textarea>` boxes.

look here for more info [select method jquery](https://api.jquery.com/select/)

Answer (score 1):

```js
function copyToClipboard() {
  let textLink = document.getElementById('text');
  let textRange = document.createRange();

  textRange.selectNode(textLink);
  window.getSelection().removeAllRanges(textRange);
  window.getSelection().addRange(textRange);

  document.execCommand("Copy");

  console.log('text was copied!');
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button id="copy" onclick="copyToClipboard()">Copy</button>
  <a id="text">Copied text from the tag "A"</a>
  <textarea placeholder="Paste this copied text"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: The original poster uses jquery. Can you edit the question so it also uses jquery? Also why does this work and the original poster's code not?

Comment: @Mathyn My code didnt work because I was using .select() which I now know works for input fields/textareas only.